# Using beautifulsoup to parse string efficiently

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to parse this html to get the item title (e.g. Big Boss Air Fryer - Healthy 1300-Watt Super Sized 16-Quart, Fryer 5 Colors -NEW)

```
<div style="" class="">
    <h1 class="it-ttl" itemprop="name" id="itemTitle"><span class="g-hdn">Details about  &nbsp;</span>Big Boss Air Fryer - Healthy 1300-Watt Super Sized 16-Quart, Fryer 5 Colors -NEW</h1>
            <h2 id="subTitle" class="it-sttl">
            Brand New + Free Shipping, Satisfaction Guaranteed! </h2>
    <!-- DO NOT change linkToTagId="rwid" as the catalog response has this ID set  -->
    <div class="vi-hdops-three-clmn-fix">           
        <div style="" class="vi-notify-new-bg-wrapper">
                <div class="vi-notify-new-bg-dTop" style=""> </div>
                <div id="vi_notification_new" class="vi-notify-new-bg-dBtm" style="top: -28px;"> 
                    <img src="https://ir.ebaystatic.com/rs/v/tnj4p1myre1mpff12w4j1llndmc.png" width="11" height="12" class="vi-notify-new-img" alt="Popular">
                    <span style="font-weight:bold;">5 sold in last 24 hours</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
```

I am using the following code to parse the page

```
url1 = "https://www.ebay.com/itm/Big-Boss-Air-Fryer-Healthy-1300-Watt-Super-Sized-16-Quart-Fryer-5-Colors-NEW/122454150244?    epid=2254405949&hash=item1c82d60c64:m:mqfT2XbgveSevmN5MV1iysg"

def get_single_item_data(item_url):
    source_code = requests.get(item_url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)

    for item in soup.findAll('h1', {'class':'it-ttl'}):
        print(item.string) # Use item.text

get_single_item_data(url1)
```

When I do this, beautifulsoup return 'None'.

One solution I found is to use print(item.text) instead, but now I get this 'Details about   Big Boss Air Fryer - Healthy 1300-Watt Super Sized 16-Quart, Fryer 5 Colors -NEW'(I do not want 'Details about  ').

Is there an efficient way to get the item title without having to get the text and then taking off the 'Details about   '?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of this caveat of the `.string` attribute:

> If a tag contains more than one thing, then it’s not clear what `.string` should refer to, so `.string` is defined to be `None`

Since the header element contains multiple children - it cannot be defined and defaults to `None`.

To avoid cutting of "Details about" part, you can get the first text node in a non-recursive mode:

```
soup.find('h1', {'class':'it-ttl'}).find(text=True, recursive=False)
```

Demo:

```
In [3]: soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

In [4]: print(soup.find('h1', {'class':'it-ttl'}).find(text=True, recursive=False))
Big Boss Air Fryer - Healthy 1300-Watt Super Sized 16-Quart, Fryer 5 Colors -NEW
```

Comment: What does setting (recursive=False) do in the code?

Comment: @JoeChan it just helps to get the high-level node, in this case "text" node - see more in the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-recursive-argument).

Answer (score 2):

You [sh/co]uld use `.text` instead `.string` :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url1 = "https://www.ebay.com/itm/Big-Boss-Air-Fryer-Healthy-1300-Watt-Super-Sized-16-Quart-Fryer-5-Colors-NEW/122454150244?    epid=2254405949&hash=item1c82d60c64:m:mqfT2XbgveSevmN5MV1iysg"

def get_single_item_data(item_url):
    source_code = requests.get(item_url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text,'html.parser')



    for item in soup.findAll('h1', {'class':'it-ttl'}):
        print(item.text) # Use item.text

get_single_item_data(url1)
```

output:

```
Details about   Big Boss Air Fryer - Healthy 1300-Watt Super Sized 16-Quart, Fryer 5 Colors -NEW
```